# Validating - at least one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox, forms

I have a problem in validating whether at least one checkbox is checked or not.

The same code is being used for a different form and its working perfectly but I can't figure why it doesn't on this form.

Script:

```
if(jQuery('#MOTForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) { 
       alert("1");
       valid = valid && false;
       $("#MOTFORMERROR").css('color', 'red');
       $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("*Choose at least one");
}else{
       $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("");
}
```

Html:

```
<td style="width: 10%;" rowspan="3">
    <div style="padding-left:5px;">
       <form id="MOTForm">
           <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"/> HEMS<br />
           <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"/> EMS<br /> 
           <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"/> Walk-in<br />
       </form>

       <p id="MOTFORMERROR"></p>
    </div>
</td>
```

The code in the block of the *if* statement is being run all the time, instead of the code in the block of the *else* statement, even if one or all checkboxes are checked!

Comment: There's nothing in the code you are showing here which would necessarily cause the problem. You might try quoting the attribute in your selector; e.g., `'#MOTForm input[type="checkbox"]:checked'` but I doubt that's the problem. Perhaps you have two elements with the same ID?

Comment: where is _valid_ declared/initialized initially? and when is that javascript code run? does it run when the page loads, when the form is being submitted, when another event happens (e.g. button click), etc.?

Comment: i doubled check and there is no two elements with the same id

Comment: valid is declared at the beginning of .click

Comment: when you say "the same code", you mean 100% same in the same page? If so, then this is your problem because you have duplicate ids e.g. `<form id="MOTForm">`

Comment: I would guess that the JS would be run inside of a submit or some other event handler but you didn't include one, so I am not sure. Is that true? Or is this running on page load? In which case, this would alert every time because none of the checkboxes are checked.

Comment: it runs when a submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Since the variable *valid* wasn't defined, there was an error in your initial code (see below). This error is visible in the [browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337/75755).

> Uncaught ReferenceError: valid is not defined

Because of that error, the lines after `valid = valid && false;` are not being executed.

To fix this, declare that variable before this code is run:

```
var valid = false;
//...other code to check if form is valid
```

Then move the original JavaScript code into a function that can be run on submit (e.g. `function check() {...}`). See this demonstrated below. It uses the jQuery function [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to bind the event handler to the submit button. You will also notice it uses [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to wait until the DOM is ready before binding the event handler to the submit button.

```js
//wait until DOM is ready to bind check function to button click
$(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
  $('#submit').click(check);
})
var valid = false;
function check() {
  if (jQuery('#MOTForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
    alert("1");
    valid = valid && false;
    $("#MOTFORMERROR").css('color', 'red');
    $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("*Choose at least one");
  } else {
    console.log('no error- clearing error html');
    $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-left:5px;">
  <form id="MOTForm">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" /> HEMS
    <br />
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" /> EMS
    <br />
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" /> Walk-in
    <br />

<button id="submit">
  Submit
</button>
  </form>
  <p id="MOTFORMERROR"></p>
</div>
```

#### Update:

You typed a comment on your post (replying to questions in other comments):

> valid is declared at the beginning of .click

Now that that information is revealed, it makes me feel like most of what I said above is useless. Moving the declaration of *valid* into the click handler seems like a trivial change and there isn't much different besides that... See the example below:

```js
//wait until DOM is ready to bind check function to button click
$(document).ready(function(readyEvent) {
  $('#submit').click(check);
})
function check() {
  var valid = false;
  if (jQuery('#MOTForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
    alert("1");
    valid = valid && false;
    $("#MOTFORMERROR").css('color', 'red');
    $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("*Choose at least one");
  } else {
    console.log('no error- clearing error html');
    $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-left:5px;">
  <form id="MOTForm">
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" /> HEMS
    <br />
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" /> EMS
    <br />
    <input name="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" /> Walk-in
    <br />

<button id="submit">
  Submit
</button>
  </form>
  <p id="MOTFORMERROR"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code does not show *when* the javascript is executed, maybe your checkboxes are not yet rendered when you look for them.

In fact if you run your code in the exact order you posted here is perfectly normal that your condition is always true.

If you put your code inside a function to be called after all the HTML is rendered everything works perfectly:

```
<td style="width: 10%;" rowspan="3">
    <div style="padding-left:5px;">
        <form id="MOTForm">
            <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"/> HEMS<br />
            <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"/> EMS<br />
            <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input"/> Walk-in<br />
        </form>
        <p id="MOTFORMERROR"></p>
    </div>
</td>



<!-- ... -->



<button id="check_btn">Click me</button>



<!-- ... -->



<script>
var valid;

$('#check_btn').click(function() {
    if ($('#MOTForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
        valid = false;
        $("#MOTFORMERROR").css('color', 'red');
        $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("*Choose at least one");
    } else {
        $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following snippet. It does that you are looking for. I removed the `valid` variable, since it isn't apparent, where this parameter is used. Apparently, you can add it and use it as you think.

```js
$(function(){
   
    function checkCheckBoxes(){   
        if($('#MOTForm input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) { 
           alert("1");
           $("#MOTFORMERROR").css('color', 'red');
           $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("*Choose at least one");
         } else {
           $("#MOTFORMERROR").html("");
        }
    }
    
    $(".js-check").on("change", checkCheckBoxes);
    
    checkCheckBoxes();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td style="width: 10%;" rowspan="3">
    <div style="padding-left:5px;">
        <form id="MOTForm">
            <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input js-check"/> HEMS<br />
            <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input js-check"/> EMS<br /> 
            <input name="" type="checkbox"  class="form-check-input js-check"/> Walk-in<br />
        </form>
        <p id="MOTFORMERROR"></p>
    </div>
</td>
```